# How do i remove none and implement threading to my desired output

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, class, raspberry-pi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
```

## my objective

```
"""
this is writen for the raspberry pi to get an input from two encoder and print a numberical
count. this will use with a telescope and stellarium
this need lot more work but just a beginner still
"""
```

## set gpio on raspberry init self and main varible

```
class EncoderSetup:
    def __init__(self, azm_a=27, azm_b=17, lat_a=20, lat_b=21, counter1=0, counter2=0):
        self.azm_a = azm_a
        self.azm_b = azm_b
        self.lat_a = lat_a
        self.lat_b = lat_b
        self.counter1 = counter1
        self.counter2 = counter2

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.azm_a, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.azm_b, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.lat_a, GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.lat_b, GPIO.IN)
```

## this loop gets the state of a and b compares, get direction, counts and debounces

```
class Azimuth(EncoderSetup):
    def azm_encoder(self):
        Last_RoB_Status = GPIO.input(self.azm_b)
        while not GPIO.input(self.azm_a):  # starts encoder loop
            Current_RoB_Status = GPIO.input(self.azm_b)
            dtState = GPIO.input(self.azm_a)
            if Current_RoB_Status != Last_RoB_Status:
                if dtState != Current_RoB_Status:
                    self.counter1 += 1
                else:  
                    self.counter1 -= 1
                Last_RoB_Status = Current_RoB_Status # deboucing
                # sleep(0.01)
                return self.counter1
```

## this loop gets the state of a and b compares, get direction, counts and debounces

```
class Latitude(EncoderSetup):    
    def lat_encoder(self):
    Last_RoC_Status = GPIO.input(self.lat_a)
    while not GPIO.input(self.lat_b):
        Current_RoC_Status = GPIO.input(self.lat_a)
        dtState2 = GPIO.input(self.lat_b)
        if Current_RoC_Status != Last_RoC_Status:
            if dtState2 != Current_RoC_Status:
                self.counter2 += 1
            else:
                self.counter2 -= 1
            Last_RoC_Status = Current_RoC_Status # deboucing
            # sleep(0.01)
            return self.counter2
```

## loop forever to get continous count from two encoders

```
def loop():
    eset = EncoderSetup()
    azm = Azimuth()
    lat = Latitude()
    while True:
        print ('globalCounter1 = ' + str(azm.azm_encoder()) +
            '   globalCounter2 = ' + str(lat.lat_encoder()))
```

## this doc explains my problem

```
"""
this is my problem i get a numerical output with none example
globalcounter1 = none   globalcounter2 none
globalcounter1 = 0      globalcounter2 none
globalcounter1 = none   globalcounter2 0
globalcounter1 = none   globalcounter2 none
globalcounter1 = 4      globalcounter2 -1      
globalcounter1 = 5      globalcounter2 none

the second problem is i got to turn lat_encoder first before 
i get and out from azm_encoder. i think i need to implement threading 
or the the same loop for both lat_encoder and azm_encoder
please help me i little lost at this point
"""
```

## resets the gpio on the raspberry

```
def destroy(): 
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

## start the program

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

## use to call loop to start

## remove trace back error message

```
   try: 
       loop() 
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       destroy()
```

Comment: You should really edit your question so that the indentation on the python code is valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the first problem. this whats happening

Because there are two print statements. First is inside function and second is outside function. When function not return any thing that time it return None value.

i remove the print from loop() and replaced where return statement are for
example

print self.counter1 and print self.counter2

i wonder if is possible to use the same while loop for both encoders